# Visual Studio 2010: COBOL in VS 2010, missing?

Tags: compiler-construction, visual-studio-2010, cobol

Is it true that Visual Studio 2010 has now COBOL compiler inside?

I saw this in one [article](http://bit.ly/9bEKM7).

I also saw a [video](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=-1Pi0rxjk3Y&feature=player_embedded) of it.

The question is, where can I find it? I've been searching VS2010 and still, no clues.

Thanks for answering.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I should start by pointing out that I work for Micro Focus and I'm responsible for the COBOL products so you could say I have a vested interest!

Micro Focus has had a COBOL for Visual Studio and supported managed .NET code since VS 2005 and .NET v1. The current product is called "Net Express with .NET" (OK, I know it's not a great name!). We've had a freely downloadable version for personal use but we've had to update it recently and the downloads have been suspended - should be back soon.

We've just announced our new Visual COBOL which is built on Visual Studio 2010. This is a really major update for our technology. Amongst other things, we had a review of the COBOL language to slim it down and make it much easier to use for .NET programming. Talking to some C# programmers recently they quickly understood the COBOL and could start working on the code with very little assistance. I'd better stop the promotion stuff! If you want more information, take a look at http://vs2010.microfocus.com.

A few other really useful sources of information if you're interested in COBOL with VS or .NET:

[- CSharpCorner](http://www.csharpcorner.com/)

[- Code Project](http://www.codeproject.com/info/search.aspx?artkw=cobol)

In either site, just do a search for COBOL.

Comment: AB Krishna asks: "For single user what would be the cost for Visual Cobol for Visual Studio? Thanks - AB" (posted as an answer because he doesn't have enough rep to post comments).

Answer (score 1):

There doesn't come a COBOL compiler with Visual Studio. It's probably just that it's installed on the lab computers where you found that page.<sup>1</sup> There is [COBOL for .NET](http://www.netcobol.com/products/Fujitsu-NetCOBOL-for-.NET/overview) however and they talk about Visual Studio integration there too. It may be that there are others that integrate into VS too.

---

<sup>1</sup> Similarly I don't assume that Windows comes with an Eiffel IDE, just because it's installed on our university's computers.

Answer (score 1):

COBOL is not part of VS but included through an add-on.  The install instructions can be found on the site you referenced at http://www.bgsu.edu/departments/compsci/docs/cobol.html

Answer (score 1):

You need to have [Micro Focus Visual COBOL](http://www.microfocus.com/products/micro-focus-developer/micro-focus-cobol/windows-and-net/index.aspx).  It adds those project types to the visual studio IDE.

Here is [Another link to their products](http://www.microfocus.com/products/micro-focus-developer/micro-focus-cobol/windows-and-net/micro-focus-visual-cobol.aspx).

Answer (score 1):

The Visual COBOL community is working on a Google 'knol' as a community web site about visual studio cobol. Please let us know if it can be improved, what other information you might want etc: http://knol.google.com/k/alex-turner/visual-studio-cobol/2246polgkyjfl/8#

Thanks - AJ